# How to find the derivative of a function in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, delay-differential-equations

$w(u)$ satisfies
$$
w(u)=\frac{1}{u}  \ \ \textrm{ for }1\leq u \leq 2,
$$
$$
(uw(u))'=w(u-1) \ \ \textrm{ for }u>2.
$$

I would like find numerical solutions for $w(u)'$. The derivative doesn't exist at 2 but does at all over values of $u\geq1$ I believe.

For $1 \leq u < 2$ we know $w(u)' = \frac{-1}{u^2}$.

How can I compute $w(u)'$ accurately for all other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us change a bit the notation and consider the following delay-differential equation

$$\dot{w}(t)=\dfrac{1}{t}(-w(t)+w(t-1)),t>2$$

with the initial condition $w(s)=1/s$, $s\in[1,2]$. This equivalent to the problem stated in the question where I have applied the chain rule and reorganized the terms to obtain an explicit delay-differential equation.

Now, the OP is right in saying that there is a discontinuity at for the derivative at $t=2$ since
$$\lim_{t\to 2^-}\dot{w}(t)=-1/4$$ while
$$\lim_{t\to 2^+}\dot{w}(t)=1/4.$$

In fact, this is a well-known phenomenon in delay-differential equations.

To solve for $\dot{w}(t)$, we need first to solve for $w(t)$ and this can be done by the propagation method, where we solve successively the delay-differential equation over the intervals, $[k, k+1]$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. The procedure is as follows:

- Start with the interval $[2,3]$ and solve the differential equation using any numerical method (i.e. Runge-Kutta) with "input" $w(t-1)$ equal to $1/(u-1)$. Let us call this portion $w_{2,3}$.
- Then solve for $w_{2,4}$ using $w_{2,3}$ as initial condition, etc.
- Numerically differentiate the solution to get the derivative.

It is also possible to obtain some analytical results. Over the interval $[k, k+1]$, the solution is expressed as

$$w(t)=\Psi(t,k)w(k)+\int_k^t\dfrac{1}{s}\Psi(t,s)w(s-1)ds,t\in[k,k+1]$$

where $$\Psi(t,s)=\exp\left(\int_s^{t}-\dfrac{1}{t}dt\right)=\dfrac{s}{t}.$$

This yields

$$w(t)=\dfrac{k}{t}w(k)+\dfrac{1}{t}\int_k^tw(s-1)ds,t\in[k,k+1].$$

Now, it is possible to numerically and successively integrate as

$$w(t)=\dfrac{2}{t}w(2)+\dfrac{1}{t}\log(t-1),\ t\in[2,3],$$

and this goes for all the next intervals. The issue here is that the integral may become more difficult to evaluate over time, but it can still be numerically evaluated.

Comment: This solves the problem perfectly for u between 2 and 3. I wonder if such a clean solution exists for larger u.

Comment: As explained, this is an interative algorithm in which you consider successive integration intervals. I only did the first step, the rest is analogous.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer.  I will leave it a few days to see if anyone has an alternative approach.  Maybe there is a Runge-Kutta based approach.

Comment: Yes there is. It is also explained in my post. You can numerically integrate with whatever method  suvcessively over the intervals and that include RK methods.

Comment: Thank you again for this wonderful answer.